# Is it possible to close or create a PDA from within an Anchor function

Tags: pda, anchor-lang, deletion

I know I can set this up with Anchor accounts and trigger a anchor function through client side code

```
pub fn delete_item(ctx: Context<DeleteItem>) -> Result<()> {
   Ok(())
}

pub fn add_item(ctx: Context<AddItem>) -> Result<()> {
   Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DeleteItem<'info> {
    #[account(mut, close = user)]
    pub item: Account<'info,Item>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateItem<'info> {
    #[account(mut, payer=user, space=Item::LEN, seed= [some_seed], bump)]
    pub item: Account<'info,Item>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info,System>,
}
```

But what I would like to do is to trigger deletion or creation within another Anchor function.

```
pub fn another_process(ctx: Context<AnotherItem>) -> Result<()> {
   
   ///Do some things... 

   
   ///Example: now delete item PDA through rust code here..
   ///Or create another item through function here.


   Ok(())
}
```

Is this possible? If so, what would the code look like?

Answer (score 2):

yes. This is possible.

As long as your program owns said account/PDA, you can delete it together with its contents.

but what do you mean by *another function*. Using the anchor constraint you provided when the first instruction from `DeleteItem` Accounts struct finishes executing, it will call the `close` instruction for the account.

But if you have two functions tied to the `DeleteItem`, you could remove the `close` constraint and instead use

```
        ctx.accounts.item.close(ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info())?;
```

Comment: Ok, interesting.. sorry I was updating the questions with the ability to add as well. What I meant by another function is within the function ```another_process``` can I delete a pda or create a pda there.

Comment: I also saw the confusion as I had mistakenly set ```DeleteItem```  as the context for ```another_process```. I just updated my question.